# [Android][MediaPlayer] Change surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer

When the media playback completes, 
is it possible to change surfaceview without preparing the media again?

According to my experiment result, it always dumps the following log, what is the meaning of this?

```
08-18 01:55:23.345: W/BufferQueue(436): [SurfaceView] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
08-18 01:55:23.345: W/BufferQueue(436): [SurfaceView] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
...
```

In my case, this method sometimes will cause the mediaserver death.
It was unstable. After the playback has completed, 
what is the right way to change surfaceview without preparing again the media?

Thanks.

Comment: I have noticed that this happens for me on android 4.2 - 4.0. I have not tested on older versions. On android 4.3+ it works fine. If any one comes up with a solution on the older devices I would love to know.